# Column alignment in pdfmake / jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, pdfmake

I'm using jquery datatables with the pdfmake library to generate a clientside pdf.

Is there a way to set a column alignment via the "customize" function or something like that?

Maybe there's a solution to do this like setting a custom width:

```js
customize: function ( doc ) 
{
  doc.content[2].table.widths = ["*", 100, 100];
}
```